# Addition of timestamp values

Tags: c++, c, struct, timestamp, overflow

I am trying to check for overflow when I am adding two structures whose parameters are timestamp values.
The rules for overflow:

1.The nanoseconds should be within the value MAX_NS after addition.

2.The seconds should be within the value MAX_S after addition.

3.No need to check for topseconds.(It will always be within the range)

This is function I have written for checking overflow.

```
 #include "stdio.h"

#define MAX_NS 999999999
#define MAX_S 4294967295

typedef struct
{
 int nanoseconds;
 int seconds;
 short int topsec;
}timestamp;

timestamp timeoverflow(timestamp t1,timestamp t2)
{
 int sec1,sec2,sec3,sec4;


timestamp overflow = {0,0,0};
 if((((t1.nanoseconds) + (t2.nanoseconds % MAX_NS+1))% MAX_NS+1)>MAX_NS)
 {
    overflow.nanoseconds = (((t1.nanoseconds) + (t2.nanoseconds % MAX_NS+1))% MAX_NS+1);
    sec1 =  (((t1.nanoseconds) + (t2.nanoseconds % MAX_NS+1)) / MAX_NS+1);
 }
 else
 {
    overflow.nanoseconds = (((t1.nanoseconds) + (t2.nanoseconds % MAX_NS+1))% MAX_NS+1);
 }

 sec2  = sec1 + t2.nanoseconds/MAX_NS+1;
 if(sec2 < sec1)
 {
    overflow.topsec++;
 }

 sec3 = sec2 + t2.seconds ;
  if(sec3 < sec2)
 {
    overflow.topsec++;
 }

 sec4 = sec3 + t1.seconds;
 if(sec4 < sec3)
 {
    overflow.topsec++;
 }
 overflow.seconds = sec4;

 return (overflow);
}

 int main()
 {
    timestamp t1 = {10,4294967295,2};
    timestamp t2 = {2,10,1};
    timestamp t3 = timeoverflow(t1,t2);
    printf("%d\n",t3.nanoseconds);
    printf("%d\n",t3.seconds);
    printf("%d\n",t3.topsec);


 }
```

But I am not getting the intended results .Kindly help.Thanks

**Edit** : For the given input,the ouput should be

timestamp.nanoseconds=12,

timestamp.seconds=9 and

timestamp.topsec = 4.

The output I am getting is:
timestamp.nanoseconds=14,

timestamp.seconds=10

and 
timestamp.topsec = 1.

Comment: What results are you _expecting_ to get? That is, what is your input, what is your output, and what is your desired output?

Comment: There are several problems in your timeoverflow(), for example - excess elements in struct initializer `timestamp overflow = {0,0,0,0};`. Moreover your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a main() function. Please edit your code so it's a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @kevin Boone I will pass two structures of timestamp ,they will be added in the function timeoverflow,like nanoseconds of first timestamp with nanoseconds of second timestamp ,after adding the result should not cross MAX_NS ,if it does then take modulo of the result and the quotient is added to the seconds.And the same thing needs to be done for seconds also

Comment: So is `timeroverflow` supposed to return the sum of the timestamps, after correcting for overflow, or is it supposed to return some measure of the overflow?

Comment: @Gopala Krishna In the function `timeroverflow()`, in both `if` and `else` block you have same statement - `overflow.nanoseconds = ((((t1.nanoseconds) + (t2.nanoseconds % MAX_NS+1))% MAX_NS+1);` Two questions - 1. Is the R.H.S expression is calculating overflow accurately? 2. What is the purpose of having same statement in both if and else block?

Comment: @KevinBoone It should return the sum of the timestamp and overflow check on it

Comment: I don't really see why you need to _test_ for overflow at all. Add the two nsec values together, then get the final nsec value by total_nsec%(MAX_NS+1). Get the amount to add to the seconds by integer division total_nsec/(MAX_NS+1). Then get the final sec value by adding the _three_ seconds figures -- the two original ones plus the seconds overflow from the nsec addition. Use % and / as before to reduce to range. Probably do all the arithmetic using wider integers than uint32, because the additional will probably overflow in ways that you _don't_ want, as well as those you do.

Comment: @H.S the statements in if and else statements are not same.Suppose after adding two nanoseconds the sum is 1000000001.It has overflowed and goes to the if statement.There we strip this sum into 1 ns and 1s.But if the sum is 999999999, then it goes to the else statement and copied into the ns.Here there is no second part in the else bock.

Comment: It would be so much easier to just build or borrow a 128-bit integral type, and have that hold nanoseconds.  It would be easier to build (if you can't use `__int128_t`), be higher performance, and have a greater range.  And the sizeof would be the same due to padding.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little bit late but I have some partial responses to provide you.
Your main problem is operation priority (When you make some arithmentic operations, there are some that are done before others - details can be found in [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

More factual thing concerning your code: when you do the computation of `overflow.nanoseconds` like the following :

```cpp
    overflow.nanoseconds = (((t1.nanoseconds) + (t2.nanoseconds % MAX_NS+1))% MAX_NS+1);
```

This, first, takes `something% MAX_NS` and then only makes `+1` to the result. Remember, that in `C++`, the modulo operator has the same level of precedence as multiplication and division, thus, your addition `+1` is done last (in the above operation).

To correct, this, anywhere you have `MAX_NS+1`, you should change them to `(MAX_NS+1)` so as the addition is done before. or even, better, change the value of `MAX_NS` in the declaration.
The rewritten function is as follows:

```cpp
timestamp timeoverflow(timestamp t1,timestamp t2)
{
    //timestamp t1 = {10,4294967295,2};
    int sec1,sec2,sec3,sec4;


    timestamp overflow = {0,0,0};
    if((((t1.nanoseconds) + (t2.nanoseconds % (MAX_NS+1) ))% (MAX_NS+1) )>MAX_NS)
    {
        overflow.nanoseconds = ((t1.nanoseconds + t2.nanoseconds) % (MAX_NS+1)) % (MAX_NS+1);
        sec1 =  ((t1.nanoseconds) + (t2.nanoseconds % (MAX_NS+1))) / (MAX_NS+1);
    }
    else
    {
        overflow.nanoseconds = ((t1.nanoseconds +t2.nanoseconds) % (MAX_NS+1))% (MAX_NS+1);
    }
    sec2  = (sec1 + t2.nanoseconds)/(MAX_NS+1);

    if(sec2 < sec1)
    {
        overflow.topsec++;
    }

    sec3 = sec2 + t2.seconds ;
    if(sec3 < sec2)
    {
        overflow.topsec++;
    }

    sec4 = sec3 + t1.seconds;
    if (sec4 < sec3)
    {
        overflow.topsec++;
    }

    overflow.seconds = sec4;

    return (overflow);
}
```

This allows for obtaining the values of `timestamp.nanoseconds` and `timestamp.seconds`, but I don't have enough information from your code to improve the computation of `timestamp.topsec`.

Here is my output:

```sh
nanoseconds 12
seconds 9
topsec 2
```